# Flutter: How to make buttons of the dialog box centered?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem in my dialog box, the buttons won't get centered even though I already have

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
```

in it.
My code:

```
actions: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    'Save',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    saveIssue();
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    'Cancel',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
```

My UI:

[Link for my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7BA1.png)

Comment: As per `Material design spec` dialog actions will be bottom right, you want to customize then instead of actions put your `actions` inside content only as a last child

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e7236796bd3c96e29e616f436fc3cf9aae322a64/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart#L347),  used `ButtonBar` to force the alignment, so If you want to change the alignment, you should wrap the `AlertDialog` with `ButtonBarTheme`.

```dart
class TestDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestDialog({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonBarTheme(
      data: ButtonBarThemeData(alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center),
      child: AlertDialog(
        content: Text("CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_CONTENT_"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    'Save',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    'Cancel',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The only correct answer I could find about this. All the other answers i've seen on SO, tell you to build your own buttons. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the Row widget inside actions. Just give the buttons to the actions(which is already a list type) and just use flutter's new actionsAlignment property in AlertDialog class.

```
    AlertDialog(
  actions: [],
  actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
)
```

Comment: This potentially places the buttons on the left and right edges with a large space between. However MainAxisAlignment.center places them in the center.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use Expanded to take free space.

   ```
    actions: <Widget>[
     Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         Expanded(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
           child: RaisedButton(
             child: new Text(
               'Save',
               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             color: Color(0xFF121A21),
             shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
             ),
             onPressed: () {
               saveIssue();
               Navigator.of(context).pop();
             },
           ),
         ),
         SizedBox(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
         ),
         Expanded(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
           child: RaisedButton(
             child: new Text(
               'Cancel',
               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
             ),
             color: Color(0xFF121A21),
             shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
             ),
             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.of(context).pop();
             },
           ),
         ),
         SizedBox(
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
         ),
       ],
     )
   ],
   ```

Comment: Expanded is not working sir :( I have the buttons in the dialogbox. I guess expanded doesn't work in dialogs because when I changed it to expanded then click the button to show my dialog, my dialog isn't popping out :(

Answer (score -1):

change it

```
actionsOverflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.center,
```

in AlertDialog's attributes